# Eggs and Cranes, What is the probability that it is a whooping crane’s nest?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, actuarial-science

**The problem said:**

> In a certain region, blue cranes are twice as common as whooping
>   cranes. Suppose that the number of eggs laid by a blue crane is a
>   Poisson(! = 3) random variable and the number of eggs laid by whooping
>   crane is a Poisson(! = 5) random variable. You find a crane’s nest
>   that contains 4 eggs. What is the probability that it is a whooping
>   crane’s nest?

Therefore I have:

```
B: blue cranes
W: whooping carnes
```

Pr(A)=2P(B)
B-Poisson (Lambda=3)
W-Poisson (Lambda=5)

I believe that,

P( W=4 | B+W=4) =  P( (W=4) (INTERCTION) (B+W=4))/P(B+W=4)=P(B=0)/P(B+W=4) = 0.07385

P(B=0)= e^-5

P(B+W=4)=e^(-7) (7^(4))  * 1/4! = 0.091226

But that is not correct because the book said that the correct answer is: 0.342

If someone can help me with this I will be very happy, thank for all the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

Let X1 be blue crane and X2 be whooping crane

$P(X1 = 4) = \dfrac{e^{-3}.3^4}{4!}$

$P(X2 = 4) = \dfrac{e^{-5}.5^4}{4!}$

$P(X1) = \frac{2}{3}$

$P(X2) = \frac{1}{3}$

P(4 Eggs are from X2) $= \dfrac{P(X2).P(X2 = 4)}{P(X2).P(X2 = 4)+P(X1).P(X1 = 4)}$

$= \dfrac{0.333*0.1754673}{0.333*0.1754673+.6667*0.168031356} = 0.343021158$